# How to generate typescript interfaces for graphql types using a graphql schema.json without operations?

Tags: typescript, graphql

How can i generate Typescript files from a schema.json.
Neither graphql-codegenerator nor apollo-codegen seems to provide a method to generate typescript interfaces from a schema.json without requiring a specific usage of a type in an operation.

Im struggling with this for a while now. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, can you share a snippet of what you've got in `schema.json` and your expected output? It would help to understand your question better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My schema.json has a standard introspection output.
I was struggling to find a proper way to generate my typescript interfaces.

I actually found a way to do so:

## codegen.yml

```
schema:
    - http://my-graphql-api.com/graphql
    - ./local/schema.graphql
documents:
    - ./src/**/*.graphql
overwrite: true
clientSchema: ./local/schema.graphql
generates:
    src/graphql-types.ts:
        plugins:
            - typescript
            - typescript-operations
        config:
            declarationKind:
                union: type
                type: interface
                input: interface
                scalar: interface
                arguments: interface
                interface: interface
            enumsAsTypes: true
            includeDirectives: true
            commentDescriptions: true
            flattenGeneratedTypes: true
            avoidOptionals:
                field: false
                object: false
                inputValue: false
```

And then run:
graphql-code-generator --config ./codegen.yml

https://graphql-code-generator.com/docs/plugins/typescript

is there a way to do this with apollo-codegen cli too?